# Does Identity Core TwoFactorSignIn contain a bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been working on an ASP.NET Core application for a couple months. Now near finishing the first beta I realized I hadn't enabled Two-Factor Authentication, and now I think I uncovered a bug in the implementation for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`. If we look at how a user is retrieved, it does this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the User ID claim value if present otherwise returns null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="principal">The <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> instance.</param>
    /// <returns>The User ID claim value, or null if the claim is not present.</returns>
    /// <remarks>The User ID claim is identified by <see cref="ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier"/>.</remarks>
    public virtual string GetUserId(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
        }
        return principal.FindFirstValue(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the user corresponding to the IdentityOptions.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType claim in
    /// the principal or null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="principal">The principal which contains the user id claim.</param>
    /// <returns>The user corresponding to the IdentityOptions.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType claim in
    /// the principal or null</returns>
    public virtual Task<TUser> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
        }
        var id = GetUserId(principal);
        return id == null ? Task.FromResult<TUser>(null) : FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

However, the `TwoFactorSignInAsync` method in the `SignInManager` never sets a Claims of type `UserIdClaimType`, but it sets 4 times the same `Name` claim, containing the User's `Id`.
Is this a bug in the implementation of `TwoFactorSignInAsync` or some configuration is not correct in my configuration of Identity? Which is this:

```
CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   CookieHttpOnly = true,
   LoginPath = "/User/Login",
   CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
   LogoutPath = "/User/Logout"
 };

 services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
 {
     options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie = cookieOptions;
     options.Cookies.ExternalCookie = cookieOptions;
     options.Cookies.TwoFactorRememberMeCookie = cookieOptions;
     options.Cookies.TwoFactorUserIdCookie = cookieOptions;

     options.Password = new PasswordOptions
     {
         RequiredLength = 8,
         RequireLowercase = true,
         RequireUppercase = true,
         RequireNonAlphanumeric = true
     };

     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
 })
 .AddUserStore<MyStore>()
 .AddRoleStore<MyStore>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

For the GitHub issue, please see [Does TwoFactorSignIn contain a bug or am I configuring Identity incorrectly? #981](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/981)

Comment: If you think it's a bug, post it on the ASP.NET Core Identity GitHub issue tracker. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues. StackOverflow isn't the suitable case for this kind of stuff

Comment: @Tseng Not sure if it's a bug, it could be due to how I set up Identity

Comment: You can still ask there, you'll address the developers. if it's a bug, they will mark the issue. If it's a wrong usage, they may give you the correct one and close the issue. In any case, it will be directed to the developers who can judge it at best

Comment: @Camilo, I think it is in the usage as you suggested.  Do as others have suggested. Post it on Github Issues Tracker. The team will have it sorted out and everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: The issue is posted on GitHub as per @Tseng suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@HaoK's comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/981#issuecomment-250619766):

> Two factor sign in if successful, means the NEXT request will have the
>   User set. Authentication for the current request has already happened.
>   None of the SignIn's have no effect on the current request.

The solution was to remove the GetCurrentUserAsync method after the call to TwoFactorSignInAsync which I incorrectly thought logged in the user immediatly.